# Can I use CSplitterWnd in CWnd Derived class?

Tags: mfc

I have a MFC class derived from `CWnd` directly, not from `CFrameWnd`, And I use a CSplitterWnd as a member variable to create a Splitter and two views in `OnCreate` message handler.

But it shows nothing in the client area.

What's wrong with my approach? Do I have to use a CFrameWnd derived class?

Thanks

Code Snippet:

```c
// CMyWnd.h
class CMyWnd : public: CWnd
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyWnd)
 public:
    CMyWnd();
    virtual ~CMyWnd();
    // blahblah

 protected:
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
 private:
    CXTPSplitterWnd m_WndSplitter;
}


// CMyWnd.cpp
int CMyWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!m_WndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 2, 1))
        return -1;

    if (
       !m_WndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CEditView),
                                CSize(100, 100), NULL) ||
       !m_WndSplitter.CreateView(1, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CEditView),
                                CSize(100, 200), NULL)
    )
    {
       m_WndSplitter.DestroyWindow();
       return -1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create views. A element derived from a CView class must reside in a CFrameWnd derived class.

You can create a splitter in a CWnd derived class, but than the splitter window must host CWnd derived windows too.

Comment: Thanks. Can I host a CFrameWnd in my CWnd and then host those two views? Because I cannot change the CWnd-derived class to CFrameWnd-derived class

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure if a CFrameWnd is allowed to be a child. But I am sure that you can derive you CWnd from CFrameWnd. Why shouldn't this be possible. And why not deriving the CVIew classes form a CWnd. Are you sure you have a doc view architecture. If so you need a frame anyhow.

Comment: I am maintaining some code, in which I must derive my class from CXXX, an internal class, which in turn derive from CWnd directly, therefore I say I cannot use CFrameWnd-derived class. And for the views actually I want to use CFormView, dialog-based views, hah.

Comment: Check what is the usage of this internal class. If it is about general subclassing you can still use it too.

Comment: nope. It's just about some interfaces which will be managed by some high level window manager.

Comment: In this case derive the Interfaces directly... there should be a Chance to use the Interfaces directly and not this CWnd baseclass.